# update records that are there in .csv file which will be given as input

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have .csv file with list of Ids, using those IDs in file- giving them as input, I need to update the record in table,

I have around 4000 Ids so 4000 update statements are not possible, need a procedure to automate this.

can you please tell me if there is any procedure to make this happen.

Comment: You're probably looking for [external tables](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm).

Comment: @mustaccio, is there any other way, please explain- the IDs in .csv or .txt file should be fetched and procedure will have update statement, these IDs are passed in where clause and using them the update statement runs on other updating values in other column and all 4000 records will be updated.

Comment: External table is a common table - except it is external. The only difference is in specific CREATE TABLE stmt for it. In any DML it acts as a regular Oracle's table. In your case it will be one UPDATE stmt which will update all records which must be updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an external table that references the data in your CSV.
You'll need a directory object creating that points to the location on the file system; in this case MY_DIR.

```
CREATE TABLE update_ids_ext
(
  rec_id               NUMBER,
  update_value         VARCHAR2(100)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY my_dir
     ACCESS PARAMETERS 
       ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY '\r\n'
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
      OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
      MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
      (  rec_id ,
         update_value
      )
        )
     LOCATION (MY_DIR:'update_ids.csv')
  )
```

You can then just refer to your CSV file as if it were a table and perform an update however you like. 
I've done an example using a merge and another using an update but the choice is yours.

```
MERGE INTO target_table tgt
 USING (SELECT rec_id, update_value   
          FROM update_ids_ext ) src
 ON (tgt.rec_id = src.rec_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET tgt.column_value = src.update_value; 

UPDATE target_table tgt
   SET ( tgt.column_value ) = (SELECT src.update_value         
                                 FROM update_ids_ext src
                                WHERE tgt.rec_id = src.rec_id)
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM update_ids_ext src
                WHERE tgt.rec_id = src.rec_id)
```

You probably need to look at the documentation for directory objects and external tables and possibly merge and update.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I am getting this error-ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout
ORA-30653: reject limit reached
29913. 00000 -  "error in executing %s callout"
*Cause:    The execution of the specified callout caused an error.
*Action:   Examine the error messages take appropriate action.

Comment: When Oracle reads the records from the CSV it will reject them if they don't match the format you have declared in the external table. Look in the location of the directory objet and there will be log files and reject files. they should tell you what is wrong with the table. You haven't said what the layout of your CSV is so the example above should be modified to match what you actually have.